# Templates are not loading in IE11

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My ui-router and custom directive templates are not loading in Internet Explorer 11. This is the error for each one:

```
[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: blah/blah.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
```

Everything is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Any pointers or guesses of why this maybe happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript, In Internet Explorer, there is normally an issue because of 'use-strict' mode. If your application appears to somewhere have an object with two properties of the same name, 'use-strict' will cause it to crash.

For HTML, there must be a missing closing or an opening tag  which is not rendering the pages

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is fixed. There was an ES6 endsWith() method being used which is unsupported in IE11. There was no error regarding this in the console - I found the issue by ensuring "Break on all exceptions" was select in the IE dev tools debugger. The fix was to simply add a polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith